# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

I am tring to perform the following sql query to check if the name that was inserted to the form already created as taxonomy name. But I keep getting this error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column `'test'` in `'where clause'`: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE name = test;` Array ( ) in `get_google_map_api()` (line 79 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Drupal/sites/all/modules/toodate/toodate.module).

my function is:

```
function get_google_map_api($item){
    $city_name = $item;
    $chack_if_is_taxonomy = (db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE name = ".$city_name));       
    var_dump($chack_if_is_taxonomy);
    drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: you error does not seem to match the code..? test column is not there in the where clause which u might have entered earlier.

Comment: You are right, I've edited my text

Comment: is the error still occuring ? Pls update the error which correlates to the code.

Comment: Yes the error is still occurring. I did update the error

Comment: What is test ? is it a column or a variable ?

Comment: test is the variable that pass through $item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix would be adding the missing single quotes around your variable. Forgetting the quotes can throw odd errors from this function, such as mixing a string for a column, like in your case.

There are less error prone ways to make short queries like this. See also Molot's answer.

Comment: Thanks, But it didn't show what I wanted to get... I'll post another question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use [`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) unless you really have to. Build your queries with [`db_select()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7). It's harder to make SQL errors using it. Your query would look like this:

```
// SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE name = $city_name
$chack_if_is_taxonomy = db_query('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd');
$chack_if_is_taxonomy->addField('ttd', 'COUNT(*)', 'count');
$chack_if_is_taxonomy->condition('name', $city_name, '=');
```

As you can see, no place to make SQL errors, and PHP bugs should be easier to spot in your favourite IDE.